# Handling abrupt PayPal payment cancellations

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have an ASP.net application.

The User can purchase 1 of my products via PayPal.

When the User is redirected to the PayPal site for confirmation and processing of the payment what happens if the User does not make the payment but also closes the web page rather than the cancel button?

How long should I wait to see if an order has gone though (or not)? Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes I did read it but I did not find out what to do if the user closes the browser instead of pressing 'cancel' on the paypal page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that paypal informs you for a payment, or a cancellation, or an issue in general. These are the:

- [Payment Data Transfer (PDT)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/)
- [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

The PDT is data that paypal send you when the user is return back to your page, and IPN are data that send you dynamically even if user did not return back to you.

The suggestions is to implement both of this on your site. There are sdk and asp.net samples direct from PayPal on how to do it, and all the details about.

On the links above there all you need to know to develop it.

Especial to your question, this [IPN page, have examples](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) on how to capture infomations about payments even if the user did not come back.

[image]

If a payment is not done with in 30 minutes, the you can consider it canceled, because the session of the payment on paypal side is less than 30 minutes.

More details on session: **The paypal session is 15 minutes** if user did not do anything. Consider now that if user go for the payment, and fails, eventually will stop interactive with pp after some minutes. So we have 15 minutes paypal session + some minutes for user tries to pay, you have at least 30 minutes that you can wait the user to pay.

If the user, cancel, or close and come back to use, and ask again for to pay, then you - and paypal creates a new order id, and the payment will be be done on the second order id (not on the first)

And here are some samples code : http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks for the 30min time-out info that was specifically what I needed to know.  The links you kindly give me will help me for all the other stuff. Many Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You can get also a lot of help here: http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/

Comment: @AndrewSimpson In general search for "asp.net ipn paypal examples", there are direct on asp.net but I can not locate it now.

Comment: Hi again. Just thought of 1 potential issue though. If the User closes the browser button and I have put in my code a 30 minute 'wait' for that particular User action. Then if the User had made a mistake by closing the browser page and IMMEDIATELY wanted to press the pay button on my site then they will have to wait 30 mins to be able to make that payment?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson The second time that user go again to pay, paypal (and you) creates a new fully order, different from the last one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the extra info.  I will have to do this then.. If the User closes web page without paying I will then wait until a max of 30mins from the last logged order data for the order to be cancelled . If they know they closed and cancelled the order then they can make another payment attempt anytime.  If they are unsure whether payment went through they can wait for 30 mins..